# Read JPEG Images and append them to an array

Tags: r, lapply

I need to read a all the JPG images from a directory and make a matrix of the images. Each row should be the image. and the Columns of each row be all the pixels in the image. In my case 24 columns, since the images are 6x4 pixels

Here is what I have so far. However do I convert **list_of_images_bw_resized** to a matrix of the said dimensions?

```
files <- list.files(path = "./data/", pattern = ".JPG", all.files = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) 
list_of_images <- lapply(files, load.image) 
list_of_images_bw <- lapply(list_of_images, grayscale)
list_of_images_bw_resized <- lapply(list_of_images_bw, resize, size_x = 6, size_y = 4 )
```

Comment: What package are you using? What does your desired result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
m <- matrix(data = unlist(list_of_images_bw_resized),
            nrow = nimages, ncol = 24, byrow = TRUE)
```

Where `nimages` is the number of images in list or `length` of `list`.